# With different configurations in a solution, how can you specify different build types (DLL or Static Lib) for a project in the solution?

Tags: dll, configuration, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries

I have a VisualStudio solution with multiple projects and configurations.

For one of the projects I want to use different configuration types (DLL or Static Lib) for different configurations.

For example for the configuration "Debug|Win32" I want to build a DLL for that project, and for configuration "Static Release|x64" I want to build a Static Library.

When I try to set the configuration type for one of these configurations, this is the type that then is set for all configurations, so it seems always to be "DLL" for all configs or "Static Lib" for all configs.

I have an example where this can be different and I can't work out how this was achieved. Or do you have to 'hack' the vcxproj file ?

Comment: You need separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out that this is possible, but you need to edit the project file.

The project file is in xml format and you should find entries like this

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">...</PropertyGroup>
```

Within a `PropertyGroup` with a condition, add the `ConfigurationType` you require, so for example

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
  <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
  <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
</PropertyGroup>
```

becomes

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
  <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
  <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've found that this works, but as usual be careful when editing the xml by hand, make sure you have a backup in case you mess up syntax or xml nesting.